# Docker scale with deterministic port binding

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to scale a `wildfly` container having exposed multiple ports with deterministic results.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  wildfly-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        admin_user: admin
        admin_password: admin
    deploy:
      resources:
          limits:
            memory: 1.5G
            cpus: "1.5"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000-8099:8080"
      - "8100-8199:9990"
      - "8200-8299:8787"
    expose:
      - "8080"
      - "9990"
      - "8787"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:16.0.0.Final

# DOCKER ENV VARIABLES
ENV WILDFLY_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly
ENV STANDALONE_DIR ${WILDFLY_HOME}/standalone
ENV DEPLOYMENT_DIR ${STANDALONE_DIR}/deployments
ENV CONFIGURATION_DIR ${STANDALONE_DIR}/configuration

RUN ${WILDFLY_HOME}/bin/add-user.sh ${admin_user} ${admin_password} --silent

# OPENING DEBUG PORT
RUN rm ${WILDFLY_HOME}/bin/standalone.conf
ADD standalone.conf ${WILDFLY_HOME}/bin/

# SET JAVA ENV VARS
RUN rm ${CONFIGURATION_DIR}/standalone.xml
ADD standalone.xml ${CONFIGURATION_DIR}/
```

**Command to start**

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --scale wildfly-server=10
```

It almost works as I want to, but there is some port discrepancy. When I create the containers, I want them to have incremental ports for each container to be exposed as follows:

```
machine_1 8001, 8101, 82001
machine_2 8002, 8102, 82002
machine_3 8003, 8103, 82003
```

But what I get as a result is not deterministic and looks like this:

```
machine_1 8001, 8102, 82003
machine_2 8002, 8101, 82001
machine_3 8003, 8103, 82002
```

The problem is that every time I run the compose up command, the ports are different for each container.

Example output:

```
CONTAINER ID  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                    NAMES
0232f24fbca4  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8028->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8231->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8126->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_7
13a6a365a552  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8031->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8230->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8131->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_10
bf8260d9874d  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8029->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8228->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8129->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_6
3d58f2e9bdfe  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8030->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8229->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8130->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_9
7824a73a09f5  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8027->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8227->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8128->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_3
85425462259d  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8024->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8224->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8124->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_2
5be5bbe8e577  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8026->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8226->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8127->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_8
2512fc0643a3  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8023->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8223->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8123->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_5
b156de688dcb  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8025->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8225->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8125->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_4
3e9401552b0a  "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8022->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8222->8787/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8122->9990/tcp   wildfly-server_1
```

***Question***

Is there any way to make the port distribution deterministic? Like disable parallel running to have serial checks on the available ports or any other method? The only alternative I found is to have a `yml`  template and generate all the necessary files (like 10 if I need 10 containers etc). Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: if you use CI server like jenkins you can handel that simply

Comment: The environment is not a fixed one. The goal is basically to pop it up anywhere as many instances as needed. I can solve it with the mentioned `yml` template with different environment variables, but I am interested if there is any way to use the `--scale` to do so.

Comment: is there any reason preventing you to use Swarm mode?

Comment: How would you utilize swarm mode to create multiple instances with sequential ports and with deterministic port binding?

Comment: You want to run multiple instance, when you send a request then it will go to one of the available instance. Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: No. I do not want load balancing. I need to assign the containers to different users.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot  currently (10/14/19) make the port selection deterministic in the docker-compose file. This behavior was requested in Github issues [#722](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/722) and [#1247](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1241), but those issues were closed without the issue having been implemented.

If you want to semi-dynamically scale an application like it sounds like you do, then you'll need to solve this another way. Your `.yml` templating idea sounds like the cleanest solution IMO.

Are you sure you need the ports to be deterministic? If you use a reverse proxy like nginx that listens on  one host port and balances the load between all of your docker containers, would that work for your use case? Setting up an nginx load balancer in a docker container is pretty straightforward. I suggest you look into that, and if you still need a deterministic way for a caller to know the service's port so it can send a request to a specific server repeatedly, then go with your `.yml` templating solution or some kind of service discovery process separate from the docker-compose configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I am a bit disappointed that they did not even address the problem... I want to scale fully automatically. :) I need deterministic ports to generate some files before the containers are up (each port should be for a different user so as I commented before load balancing is not an option). So the information you have shared is more like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: So in that case, you are not really "dynamically scaling" in a way that docker-compose and docker are equipped to handle. They are expecting the instances of your service to be fully interchangeable, and in your case they're not... you either need some kind of service discovery mechanism or deterministic assignment of ports, and I think your `.yml` templating approach is the quickest, easiest solution. And btw, I technically answered your question of "Is there any way to make the port distribution deterministic?" :) but I apologize that I couldn't suggest a more helpful solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using variable substitution:

```
yaml:
...
   ports:
      ${PORT}:8080
```

Then call docker with the specific ports:

```
for p in {8000..8099}; do
   PORT=$p docker-compose ...
done
```

Comment: This is not really a different solution compared to the yaml template generation mentioned in the question, but could be an alternative to that. Thanks for the idea.